# How to display products from external API in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to integrate products from live external api into prestashop 1.6, so user can add them to cart and make orders also.

I found a solution to override the function that call products from Database but the website countaine modules that call products directely from database (it is not solution to override the modules also, because if there is a new ones it hard to do the same work).

I'm waiting for you solutions.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I see two solutions:
- You import the products in question in your Prestashop shop
- You change the product classes, Categories, etc ... to no longer query on the database, but on your API

Regards,

Comment: -- The second solution is not going to work because there is other modules that call database directly ( without using classes)

-- The first one seems the best but how can i make the import everytime (THE API is LIVE)

Comment: For the first solution, you have to load all the products, and every X time will check in the API if you have new products. On the other hand, the fact that modules call products without native classes is that the modules have not been developed correctly.

Comment: Thank you. To execute the import every X time, should I use cron job ?

Comment: Yes cron job is the best solution

Comment: I have a problem. The import take toooooooooooooo much time. I have just to add 50 product. how can i speed the process (ps : to add one i use the product class) ?

Comment: To go faster, it is necessary to deactivate all the modules graft on the product hooks (create and update). Then you have to see server side if you want to accelerate more. We are able to import 100,000 products in 3-4H with well-optimized scripts and a correct server.